# Setting margin-up calendar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem while selecting date (using bootstrap class datepicker), after running the snippet, the calendar shows below textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="due_date" id="due_date" onclick="calendar_up()" value="" placeholder="Due Date">
```

I want that the calendar should appear above the textbox, I have written the script but it's not working,

```
    <script> 
          function calendar_up(){
          document.getElementById('due_date').style.marginTop = Value.ToString() + '150px';
          }
   </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it should be `onclick="calendor_up()"` You are missing `()`

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add this '()' but still not working I thing there is a problem in script

Comment: I'm not sure if it is work or not "document.getElementById(due_date)" or it will be "document.getElementById('due_date')"?

Comment: Are you trying to add `marginTop`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you try this line of code: "document.getElementById('due_date').style.marginTop = Value.ToString() + '150px';" Or "document.getElementById(document.due_date).style.marginTop = Value.ToString() + '150px';"

Comment: yup just tried but same problem

Comment: I tried with your code. Showing error with "Value.ToString()". But when I tried this code it is adding margin on top properly:  document.getElementById('due_date').style.marginTop = '150px';

Answer (score 2):

In you HTML you need to use this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="due_date" id="due_date" onclick="calendor_up()" value="" placeholder="Due Date">
```